# Is there a way around data flow diagrams rules?

Tags: dataflow, dataflow-diagram

Can data come out of a data store and then be processed and then go to an external entity?

[image: the image shows that cold water going to reservoir and then to the heater through U-shaped tubes and then to sprinkler and into container which would process coffee beans and hot water and pour into jug]

My question is that is it ok that data (coffee and hot water) are coming out of a data store (container) and then are processed into coffee and then poured into an external entity which is the jig? Is this dfd obeying dfd rules?

Comment: Hi, can you please add an image which might describe your current dfd?

Comment: I did, can u examine it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. DFDs can never contain `user` as an entity, rather you should represent some functionalities through which the data flows eg. login, authentication etc
2. Your data here seems correct , you can just optimize the parallel flows using `joins` and `forks`

Comment: Ok thanks so much fpr your time this was for exam practice. And i should just replace user with "coffee contents" cause coffee maker wouldn't have any sort of login or authentication, right?

Comment: Yes true , also check  `join` `fork` and let me know if you have any more queries

Comment: I know this is weird but in system modelling, we show the major subsystem and the relationship between them, right? Can we, like, add dfds in a system model diagram because i googled system modelling and saw alot of dfds?